# Manipulacion del DOM con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Tengo este código HTML

```
<ul id="categories">
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Animals</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>Cat</li>
          <li>Hamster</li>
          <li>Horse</li>
          <li>Parrot</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Products</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>Bread</li>
          <li>Prasley</li>
          <li>Cheese</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Technologies</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
          <li>React</li>
          <li>Node.js</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Estoy tratando de obtener el número de categorias con Javascript, el nombre de cada categoría y el número de subcategoria.  En la consola debería mostrarme esto:

Número de categorías: 3

Categoría: Animals
Elementos: 4

Categoría: Products
Elementos: 3

Categoría: Technologies
Elementos: 5

Tengo esto en mi código:

```
const numberOfCategories = document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
console.log(`Número de categorías: ${numberOfCategories}`);

const categoryOne = document.querySelectorAll(".item.h2");
console.log(categryOne[0]);
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Obtenemos la lista de categorías con el selector `#categories > li.item`
- Esa lista la recorremos,

y en cada iteración:

- Obtenemos el nombre del `h2`
- Obtenemos los elementos `<li>` dentro de esa categoría

```js
const categorias = document.querySelectorAll("#categories > li.item");
console.log(`Número de categorías: ${categorias.length}`);

categorias.forEach(e=>{
   let nombre = e.querySelector("h2").innerText;
   let elementos =  e.querySelectorAll("li");
   console.log(`Categoría: ${nombre} Elementos: ${elementos.length}`);
});
```

```html
<ul id="categories">
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Animals</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>Cat</li>
          <li>Hamster</li>
          <li>Horse</li>
          <li>Parrot</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Products</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>Bread</li>
          <li>Prasley</li>
          <li>Cheese</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <h2>Technologies</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
          <li>React</li>
          <li>Node.js</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vemos que en tu listado hay 3 clases llamados `item`, en donde cada clase contiene distinta categoría.

No es que me desborde del tema, pero en CSS existe la *pseudoclase* llamado `nth-of-type()`, en donde según su [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

> *La pseudoclase **:nth-of-type()** de CSS selecciona uno o más elementos de un tipo dado, en función de su posición entre un grupo de hermanos.*

---

Ahora, sabemos que esto vendría a ser un selector, entonces, con `querySelectorAll()` podemos indicar a qué clase `item` queremos seleccionar. Por ejemplo, yo al hacer esto:

```
const animalsCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(1)").length;
```

Indico que estoy seleccionando solamente al contenido de la primera clase `item`, que vendría a ser el listado de animales. ¿Por qué al primero?, pues porque del `nth-of-type` le indico al `1` como su argumento. Si coloco el `2`, seleccionamos al contenido de la segunda clase `item`, sucesivamente.

Entonces, con esto ya lo tendrías, ingresas a cada clase y mides su longitud de elementos `li` que contiene, así:

```
const animalsCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(1) li").length;
const productsCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(2) li").length;
const technologiesCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(3) li").length;
```

Código completo:

```js
const numberOfCategories = document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;

const animalsCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(1) li").length;
const productsCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(2) li").length;
const technologiesCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".item:nth-of-type(3) li").length;

console.log(`Número de categorías: ${numberOfCategories}`);
console.log(`Categoría: Animals Elementos: ${animalsCategory}`);
console.log(`Categoría: Products Elementos: ${productsCategory}`);
console.log(`Categoría: Technologies Elementos: ${technologiesCategory}`);
```

```html
<ul id="categories">
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Animals</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Cat</li>
      <li>Hamster</li>
      <li>Horse</li>
      <li>Parrot</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Bread</li>
      <li>Prasley</li>
      <li>Cheese</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Technologies</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>React</li>
      <li>Node.js</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```